# What is the best way to signal LinkedBlockingDeque client to stop consuming?

Tags: java, multithreading, deque

What is the best way to signal LinkedBlockingDeque client to stop consuming?

The serving thread will stop writing to the Deque, but consuming thread will block if the queue is empty. The thing I need to do is to let consuming thread take everything from the queue and shut down. Is interrupt good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.interrupt()` is generally not good idea as it could cause interrupting the work that the thread is currently working on.

More reliable way is to use some kind of special message, i.e. send special object which would be interpreted as signal to end by the consumer.

Or, rather consider using `ExecutorService` for this and its [shutdown method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) which can do the work easily and it's standard solution for this kind of problems.